# Metatag Discription on site

Tags: seo

i have Wordpress site i Use Bethemes
purpas of this site is bloging 
in home page it will display 2 meta discription tag one is site meta discription 
second one is first Blog meta discription

Comment: WordPress doesn’t display meta tags on its own. You must be using a plugin (or two). You need to take this up with it’s author.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the default installation, WordPress does not include meta tags such as description and keywords. First check weather you have any Plugin installed which is including another Description Tag .. if not then check your beetheme... 
if you have downloaded the pirated means from other free download websites then you need to uninstall it first...  if none can work then install yoast plugin .. activate it and then check..
Please upvote my Answer ....